# Xbox 360 controller and wireless receiver not working

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

I have a Microsoft brand Xbox 360 wireless receiver plugged into a USB hub and a controller that came with an Xbox 360. In the past, I would have trouble getting the controller and receiver to work with my PC, however it has worked before.

Now, it has a new problem: Once the controller connects (and I can see it in devices and printers), everything is OK until I move one of the analog sticks, then suddenly nothing works, not even if I reconnect the receiver.

There's more. My PC setup is set up to allow the USB hub be re-plugged into a USB device on my desk, and sometimes I plugged it into my tablet so I can play mobile games with a controller. Except, LT and RT side buttons are acting as the X and Y axis for the right joystick. I'm not sure if it has to do with the problem above, but it is very annoying.

Is there a fix to either of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, try installing the drivers from the disk/outdated drivers first, as this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller buttons might be set differently, did you mess with calibration? If not try installing latest drivers on the Microsoft website.